# SAS Proc Tabulate create calculated column

Tags: sas

I am trying to add two columns together in proc tabulate but haven't seen any literature online on how to do this.  I have two columns, CHRG_TOT and CHRG_ELIG.  I would like to subtract CHRG_ELIG from CHRG_TOT therefore creating a new variable called Diff.  Below is my code.

```
        PROC TABULATE
    
    DATA=CLAIMS.t_claims6;
    
        
    
         VAR QUANTITY CHRG_TOT CHRG_ELIG Savings Percent_Savings Allow_per_Service;
    
         CLASS Lab_Code / ORDER=UNFORMATTED MISSING;
    
         CLASS CPT_DESCP /     ORDER=UNFORMATTED MISSING;
    
         CLASS SERVICE_TYPE2 / ORDER=FORMATTED;
    
         CLASS Incurred_Year / ORDER=UNFORMATTED MISSING;
    
         LABEL CHRG_TOT = Chrg Tot;
    
         LABEL QUANTITY = Quantity;
    
         LABEL CHRG_ELIG = Chrg Elig;
    
         LABEL Percent_Savings = Percent Savings;
    
         LABEL Allow_per_Service = Allow per Service;
    
         TABLE
    
               /* ROW Statement */
    
               Lab_Code * CPT_DESCP
    
               all = 'Total'  ,
    
               /* COLUMN Statement */
    
               SERVICE_TYPE2 = '' *Incurred_Year = '' *(QUANTITY * Sum={LABEL=""} CHRG_TOT * Sum={LABEL=""} CHRG_ELIG * Sum={LABEL=""} Savings * Sum={LABEL=""} Percent_Savings * Sum={LABEL=""} Allow_per_Service * Sum={LABEL=""}  )
    
               all = 'Total'  *(QUANTITY * Sum={LABEL=""} CHRG_TOT * Sum={LABEL=""} CHRG_ELIG * Sum={LABEL=""} Savings * Sum={LABEL=""} Percent_Savings * Sum={LABEL=""} Allow_per_Service * Sum={LABEL=""} ) / MISSTEXT= '0' nocellmerge;
    
               FORMAT SERVICE_TYPE2 $SrvType. ;
    
    RUN;
```

Comment: You cannot add columns together in TABULATE you may need REPORT instead in that case.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Tabulate does have the `OUT=` option so you can pipe the outputs from tabulate to report and use it to display without too much extra work to calculate other things.